# how to check condition in multidimensional arrays without using foreach in php

Tags: php

I want to use if condition to check state == runner_accepted when i get first time runner_accepted second time reached_for_pickup..

first time:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [state] => runner_accepted
        )
)
```

second time:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [state] => reached_for_pickup
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [state] => runner_accepted
   )
)
```

i want final result when i check:
first time:

```
if(state == runner_accepted){ echo "active"; }else{ echo "inactive"; }
```

second time:

`if(state == reached_for_pickup){ echo "active"; }else{ echo "inactive"; }`

Comment: Use `array_comun` to extract those `state` values into a flat array; use `in_array` on that afterwards to perform your check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_reduce` function to iterate over the array and apply the condition to each element.

Here is an example

```php
<?php

$arr = [
  [
    'state' => 'reached_for_pickup',
  ],
  [
    'state' => 'runner_accepted'
  ]
];

$arr2 = [
  [
    'state' => 'reached_for_pickup',
  ]
];


$callback = function ($carry, $item)
{
  if ($item['state'] == 'runner_accepted') {
    return true;
  }

  return $carry;
};

$result = array_reduce($arr, $callback, false);
$result2 = array_reduce($arr2, $callback, false);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($result2);
```